# Custom Keyboard Shortcut to switch tabs in Photoshop on Mac

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, keyboard-shortcuts, adobe-photoshop

In Photoshop on Mac OS X I would like to program `Command-Shift-[` and `Command-Shift-]` to switch between tabs (the different open files). I don't mind losing their functionality as Send-to-Front / Send-to-Back, but I can't figure out where I need to put them in on the "Keyboard Shortcuts and Menus" editor. Help!

Comment: From a deleted answer: Photoshop already has keyboard shortcut `Control + Tab` to switch between tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This answer is not Photoshop-specific, but might work anyway, if it's a reasonably well-behaved OS X application.*

If there are menu items for these commands (like *Select Next Tab* in Safari's *Window* menu), you can assign them different keyboard shortcuts in *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts » Application Shortcuts*

Select the application (e.g. *Safari*), enter the menu item title (e.g. *Select Next Tab*) and  enter the desired keyboard shortcut (e.g. `Cmd-Shift-[`).

Result:

[image]

---

The same preference pane contains the OS X global shortcut for cycling through an application's windows:

[image]

Change this setting to change it for all applications.

Comment: I knew these things existed, but didn't think they would apply. After reading your solution I did have the idea that Photoshop was overriding the default actions for those keys, and so I should "unset" them in Photoshop, hoping they would function as they do in other applications. Unfortunately it didn't work. I wish I could use your method, but as far as I can tell the options are simply not in the menu anywhere. http://s3.postimage.org/iy2so9tw5/photoshop.jpg

Comment: @cwd The second suggestion also doesn't work with the global shortcut? I'm not a PS user, so I can't experiment myself.

Comment: I tried to define a Photoshop specific keyboard shortcut with method #2, but I got an error http://s2.postimage.org/ltlapry63/Picture_2.png I also redefined the <code>Command-`</code> shortcut but it did not change the default behavior in Photoshop, as far as I can tell. I'm so used to using the Command combination in other apps to switch between windows - I wish Photoshop would let me set it up to do the same thing.

Comment: @cwd Interesting. I've honestly never encountered this before. I refer you to the second sentence of my answer for an explanation :-) Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Press Command (Control on Windows) and the ~ (the tilde key)
Here is a link to more info:  http://vectips.com/tips-and-tricks/quick-tip-quickly-switch-between-open-tabbed-documents/

Comment: Please expand upon your answer—link-only answers aren't very useful by themselves and can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This only cycles through all open documents, rather than cycling forward and backward through open tabs within a single window.